# C++ pointers struct's and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

Please can someone explain to my adlers brain why is goulash not equal to 123.222?

To explain goulash is a pointer variable set to 123.222 for each thread however when the thread's are activated and passed the pointer via the thread function null pointer the output is sadly 0 for each thread and not 123.222 as it should be.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>


typedef struct
{

int blossom;
double goulash;

}juniper;

juniper **jeffery;
juniper **james;

typedef struct{

int rodent_teeth;
juniper **raymond;

}rosebud;


void * thread_function(void *p){

juniper *monty = (juniper *) p;

printf("Goulash = %f\n",monty->goulash);

}


int main(){

int i;
rosebud *hattys_friend;

hattys_friend = (rosebud*) calloc(1,sizeof(rosebud));

hattys_friend->raymond = (juniper**) calloc(10,sizeof(juniper*));

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
hattys_friend->raymond[i] = (juniper*) calloc(10,sizeof(juniper));
        }

hattys_friend->raymond[2]->goulash = 5.6;

pthread_t threads[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

hattys_friend->raymond[i]->goulash = 123.222;
hattys_friend->rodent_teeth = i;

pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,thread_function,(void*) &hattys_friend->raymond[i]);

printf("creating thread %d\n",i);

}

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);


}





jeffery = &hattys_friend->raymond[2];

james = hattys_friend->raymond;






printf("jeffery -> goulash = %f\n",(*jeffery)->goulash);


printf("james -> goulash = %f\n",(*(james+2))->goulash);

hattys_friend->raymond[2]->goulash = 1.6;

printf("james -> goulash = %f\n",(*(james+2))->goulash);


}
```

Comment: What is this, IOCCC code? What's with the insane variable names?

Comment: Not to be mean or anything but this really made me laugh :D

Comment: @nneonneo lol. that was awesome.

Comment: Can you answer the question though? The names are random its a thought experiment trying to answer this for something bigger that wont ctrl-k

Comment: -1, I'm not going to read obfuscated code. Someone else can do that. Or, you could provide a simpler, readable example.

Comment: One of your `juniper`s should definitely be called `Jennifer`. (Meh, I'm old, so what?)

Comment: what is this a writing contest? just wanted to know why the pointer isnt carried over in the multithreading example

Comment: dont look at the variable names theyre not important see the code neo I mean Daniel, be the code

Comment: read a good book - dont try to find meaning in IOCCC. I am trying to work on a PWM module for a microcontroller project but I need to tie down these multi-threading tutorial, if my professer finds out you said his code was IOCCC I might have reason to ask for a refund

Comment: Although you have tagged the question as C++, code seems to be C. If you intend to use C++ please consider using `cstdio` & `cstdlib` instead of `stdio.h` & `stdlib.h`

Comment: Ok well I assume it is because nobody is using old C to do multi-threading

Comment: Comon please help I just dont know this one!!

Comment: Could you please edit your question using more readable and significant names for variables? This may induce other users to consider the question seriously and provide an answer more than a bunch of comments asking for help.

Answer (score 4):

```
void * thread_function(void *p){
    juniper *monty = (juniper *) p;
    printf("Goulash = %f\n",monty->goulash);
}
```

Your `thread_function` expects to receive a `juniper*`, but

```
pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,thread_function,(void*) &hattys_friend->raymond[i]);
```

`hattys_friend->raymond[i]` already is a `juniper*`, so you're passing it a `juniper**`, and the access `monty->goulash` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes, changing &hattys_friend->raymond[i] to hattys_friend->raymond[i] should fix this problem.

Comment: P.s. You can use printf("%p\n", p); to output pointer values. Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass a pointer to a pointer to `juniper` objects to the threads. However, within the thread start-up routine you cast this pointer to a pointer to `juniper`. This is undefined behavior.